# how to solve lead lag error python install package?

Tags: python, installation

I am trying to use lead_lag to create a graph. However, I am getting an error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> lead_lag (from versions: 1.6, 2.0) ERROR: No matching distribution
> found for lead_lag

what should I do?

For that I am trying to install the package on the following website:

- https://github.com/philipperemy/lead-lag
- https://pypi.org/project/lead-lag/#files

Comment: What command are you running exactly, that gives you that error? `pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/philipperemy/lead-lag`?

Comment: Thanks; I am using both the recommended methods:-
# 1. Recommended for all platforms.
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/philipperemy/lead-lag

# 2. If you have python 3.9 and MacOS. Platform specific.
pip install lead_lag



getting the following error:-

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lead_lag (from versions: 1.6, 2.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for lead_lag

Comment: Hello, try running `pip install git+https://github.com/philipperemy/lead-lag.git` if you are using Windows.